# Возможно, непреднамеренное сравнение ссылок

Tags: c#, строки

Как это исправить? Это конечно не ошибка, а просто предупреждение.

Вот сам код:

```
if (SelectTypeConnectComboBox.SelectedItem == "DSL / Cable / LAN.")
{
    string[] allText = File.ReadAllLines("Settings.cfg");
    allText[48] = "NETWORK_SPEEDSETTINGS : 2";
    File.WriteAllLines("Settings.cfg", allText);
}
```

Полная ошибка:

> Возможно, непреднамеренное сравнение ссылок; для получения сравнения значений приведите левую часть к типу "string".

P.S Предупреждение тут:

```
SelectTypeConnectComboBox.SelectedItem == "DSL / Cable / LAN."
```

Comment: А какой тип у `SelectTypeConnectComboBox.SelectedItem`?

Comment: Тип ComboBox если правильно понял. Из metroFramework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведите к `string` явно:

```
if ((string)SelectTypeConnectComboBox.SelectedItem == "DSL / Cable / LAN.")
```

Но это будет правильно только при условии, что в вашем комбобоксе хранятся строки

Comment: Спасибо, все работает отлично.

Comment: @PavelErokhin, пожалуйста, рад помочь